# EmberJS: template not rendering controller properties

Tags: templates, controller, ember.js

I'm trying to setup an emberJS app, very basic. Here it is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
            <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js"></script>
            <script src="js/ember.js"></script>
            <script>
                    window.App = Ember.Application.create();

                    App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
                            firstName: "Trek",
                            lastName: "Glowacki"
                    });
            </script>
    </head>

    <body>
            <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
                    <div>
                            Name: {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
                    </div>
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

For some reason only **Name:** is rendered. Any suggestions why 'firstName' and 'lastName' are empty ?

Cheers

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/seankeating/qq4w5/3/, What version of Ember are you using?

Comment: If you are not using the latest ember, an App.initialize() might help.

Comment: check, with the newest version it works :)

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri If your problem is resolved, could you consider either remove the question, either post the answer and accept it ?

Comment: What about the case when the tempaltes are nested, say my templates are application.hbs, sample/header.hbs how will I tie a Controller to header.hbs HeaderController simply won't find the sample directory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by updating the libraries used (see answer from Sean Keating)